# Creating a function to loop columns through an equation in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

**Solution** (thanks @Peter_Evan!) in case anyone coming across this question has a similar issue

(Original question is below)

```
## get all slopes (lm coefficients) first

# list of subfields of interest to loop through
sf <- c("left_presubiculum", "right_presubiculum", 
        "left_subiculum", "right_subiculum", "left_CA1", "right_CA1",
        "left_CA3", "right_CA3", "left_CA4", "right_CA4", "left_GC-ML-DG",
        "right_GC-ML-DG")

# dependent variables are sf, independent variable common to all models in the inner lm() call is ICV
# applies the lm(subfield ~ ICV, dataset = DF) to all subfields of interest (sf) specified previously
lm.results <- lapply(sf, function(dv) {
  temp.lm <- lm(get(dv) ~ ICV, data = DF)
  coef(temp.lm)
})

# returns a list, where each element is a vector of coefficients
# do.call(rbind, ) will paste them together
lm.coef <- data.frame(sf = sf,
                      do.call(rbind, lm.results))

# tidy up name of intercept variable
names(lm.coef)[2] <- "intercept"
lm.coef

## set up all components for the equation

# matrix to store output
out <- matrix(ncol = length(sf), nrow = NROW(DF))

# name the rows after each subject
row.names(out) <- DF$Subject

# name the columns after each subfield
colnames(out) <- sf

# nested for loop that goes by subject (j) and subfield (i)
for(j in DF$Subject){
  
  for (i in sf) {
    
    slope <- lm.coef[lm.coef$sf == i, "ICV"]

    out[j,i] <-  as.numeric( DF[DF$Subject == j, i] - (slope * (DF[DF$Subject == j, "ICV"] - mean(DF$ICV))) )

  }

}

# check output
out
```

===============

**Original Question:**

I have a dataframe (DF) with 13 columns (12 different brain subfields, and one column containing total intracranial volume(ICV)) and 50 rows (each a different participant).  I'm trying to automate an equation being looped over every column for each participant.

**The data:**

```
structure(list(Subject = c("sub01", "sub02", "sub03", "sub04", 
"sub05", "sub06", "sub07", "sub08", "sub09", "sub10", "sub11", 
"sub12", "sub13", "sub14", "sub15", "sub16", "sub17", "sub18", 
"sub19", "sub20"), ICV = c(1.50813, 1.3964237, 1.6703585, 1.4641886, 
1.6351018, 1.5524641, 1.4445532, 1.6384505, 1.6152434, 1.5278011, 
1.4788126, 1.4373356, 1.4109637, 1.3634952, 1.3853583, 1.4855268, 
1.6082085, 1.5644998, 1.5617522, 1.4304141), left_subiculum = c(411.225013, 
456.168033, 492.968477, 466.030173, 533.95505, 476.465524, 448.278213, 
476.45566, 422.617374, 498.995121, 450.773906, 461.989663, 549.805272, 
452.619547, 457.545623, 451.988333, 475.885847, 490.127968, 470.686415, 
494.06548), left_CA1 = c(666.893596, 700.982955, 646.21927, 580.864234, 
721.170599, 737.413139, 737.683665, 597.392434, 594.343911, 712.781376, 
733.157168, 699.820162, 701.640861, 690.942843, 606.259484, 731.198846, 
567.70879, 648.887718, 726.219904, 712.367433), left_presubiculum = c(325.779458, 
391.252815, 352.765098, 342.67797, 390.885737, 312.857458, 326.916867, 
350.657957, 325.152464, 320.718835, 273.406949, 305.623938, 371.079722, 
315.058313, 311.376271, 319.56678, 348.343569, 349.102678, 322.39908, 
306.966008), `left_GC-ML-DG` = c(327.037756, 305.63224, 328.945065, 
238.920358, 319.494513, 305.153183, 311.347404, 259.259723, 295.369164, 
312.022281, 324.200989, 314.636501, 306.550385, 311.399107, 295.108592, 
356.197094, 251.098248, 294.76349, 317.308576, 301.800253), left_CA3 = c(275.17038, 
220.862237, 232.542718, 170.088695, 234.707172, 210.803287, 246.861975, 
171.90896, 220.83478, 236.600832, 246.842024, 239.677362, 186.599097, 
224.362411, 229.9142, 293.684776, 172.179779, 202.18936, 232.5666, 
221.896625), left_CA4 = c(277.614028, 264.575987, 286.605092, 
206.378619, 281.781858, 258.517989, 269.354864, 226.269982, 256.384436, 
271.393257, 277.928824, 265.051581, 262.307377, 266.924683, 263.038686, 
306.133918, 226.364556, 262.42823, 264.862956, 255.673948), right_subiculum = c(468.762375, 
445.35738, 446.536018, 456.73484, 521.041823, 482.768261, 487.2911, 
456.39996, 445.392976, 476.146498, 451.775611, 432.740085, 518.170065, 
487.642399, 405.564237, 487.188989, 467.854363, 479.268714, 473.212833, 
472.325916), right_CA1 = c(712.973011, 717.815214, 663.637105, 
649.614586, 711.844375, 779.212704, 862.784416, 648.925038, 648.180611, 
760.761704, 805.943016, 717.486756, 801.853608, 722.213109, 621.676321, 
791.672796, 605.35667, 637.981476, 719.805053, 722.348921), right_presubiculum = c(327.285242, 
364.937865, 288.322641, 348.30058, 341.309111, 279.429847, 333.096795, 
342.184296, 364.245998, 350.707173, 280.389853, 276.423658, 339.439377, 
321.534798, 302.164685, 328.365751, 341.660085, 305.366589, 320.04127, 
303.83284), `right_GC-ML-DG` = c(362.391907, 316.853532, 342.93274, 
282.550769, 339.792696, 357.867386, 342.512721, 277.797528, 309.585721, 
343.770416, 333.524912, 302.505077, 309.063135, 291.29361, 302.510461, 
378.682679, 255.061044, 302.545288, 313.93902, 297.167161), right_CA3 = c(307.007404, 
243.839349, 269.063801, 211.336979, 249.283479, 276.092623, 268.183349, 
202.947849, 214.642782, 247.844657, 291.206598, 235.864996, 222.285729, 
201.427853, 237.654913, 321.338801, 199.035108, 243.204203, 236.305659, 
213.386702), right_CA4 = c(312.164065, 272.905586, 297.99392, 
240.765062, 289.98697, 306.459566, 284.533068, 245.965817, 264.750571, 
296.149675, 290.66935, 264.821461, 264.920869, 246.267976, 266.07378, 
314.205819, 229.738951, 274.152503, 256.414608, 249.162404)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**The equation:**

adjustedBrain(participant1) = rawBrain(participant1) - slope*[ICV(participant1) - (mean of all ICV measures included in the calculation of the slope)]

**The code** (which is not working and I was hoping for some pointers):

```
adjusted_Brain <- function(DF, subject) {
  subfields <- colnames(select(DF, "left_presubiculum", "right_presubiculum", 
                             "left_subiculum", "right_subiculum", "left_CA1", "right_CA1",
                             "left_CA3", "right_CA3", "left_CA4", "right_CA4", "left_GC-ML-DG",
                             "right_GC-ML-DG"))
  out <- matrix(ncol = length(subfields), nrow = NROW(DF))
  for (i in seq_along(subfields)) {
    DF[i] = DF[DF$Subject == "subject", "i"] - 
      slope * (DF[DF$Subject == "subject", "ICV"] -
                     mean(DF$ICV))
  }

}
```

Getting this error:

```
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `i` doesn't exist.
```

**A few notes:**

1. The slopes for each subject for each subfield will be different (and will come from a regression) -> is there a way to specify that in the function so the slope (coefficient from the appropriate regression equation) gets called in?
2. I have my nrow set to the number of participants right now in the output because I'd like to have this run through EVERY subject across EVERY subfield and spit out a matrix with all the adjusted brain volumes... But that seems very complicated and so for now I will just settle for running each participant separately.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: did you mean to use `i` instead of `"i"` in your function?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I've edited the post to include sample data (hopefully I did this correctly).

Comment: @Onyambu I did, thank you for catching that!  But changing "i" to just i didn't make a difference (still getting an error).

Comment: It's not just the `i` that is your problem, so too is `"subject"` which should be just `subject`. Also `DF[i]` should be `DF[, i]`. Finally, although you actually ask this in your question, `slope` is nowhere defined.  

I think it would be easier if you have a minimal working example (mwe) and perhaps display what you expect the output to look like and where you store the `slope` values.

Comment: Do you want the `mean(DF$ICV)` by groups of subject or the overall mean?

Comment: Can you also include your expected outcome for at least 2-3 rows calculted manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted in the comments, there are quite a few syntax issues that prevent your code from running, as well as a few unstated requirements. That aside, I think there is enough to recommend a few improvements that you can hopefully build on. Here are the top line changes:

- You likely don't need this to be a function, but rather a nested for loop (if you want to do this with base R). As written, the code isn't flexible enough to merit a function. If you intend to apply this many times across different datasets, a function might make sense. However, it will require a much larger rewrite.
- Assuming you are fitting a simple regression via `lm`, then you can pull out the coefficient of interest via the `$` operator and indexing (see below). Some thought will need to go into how to handle different models in the loop. Here, we assume you only need one coefficient from one model.
- There are a few areas where the syntax is incorrect and a review of sub setting in base R would be helpful. Others have pointed out in the comments were some of these are.

Here is one approach were we loop through each subject (j) through each feature or subfield (i) and store them in a matrix (out). This is just an approach and will almost certainly need tweaking on your end!

```
#NOTE: the dataset your provided is saved as x in this example.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

#fit a linear model - here we assume there is only one coef. of interest, but you may need to alter
# depending on how the slope changes in each calculation                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
reg <- lm(ICV ~ right_CA3, x)

# view the coeff.
reg$coefficients

# pull out the slope by getting the coeff. of interest (via index) from the reg object
slope <- reg$coefficients[[1]]

# list of features/subfeilds to loop through
sf <- c("left_presubiculum", "right_presubiculum", 
        "left_subiculum", "right_subiculum", "left_CA1", "right_CA1",
        "left_CA3", "right_CA3", "left_CA4", "right_CA4", "left_GC-ML-DG",
        "right_GC-ML-DG")

# matrix to store output
out <- matrix(ncol = length(sf), nrow = NROW(x))

#name the rows after each subject
row.names(out) <- x$Subject

#name the columns after each sub feild
colnames(out) <- sf

# nested for loop that goes by subject (j) and features/subfeilds (i)
for(j in x$Subject){

  for (i in sf) {

    out[j,i] <-  as.numeric( x[x$Subject == j, i] - (slope * (x[x$Subject == j, "ICV"] - mean(x$ICV))) )

  }

}

# check output
out
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!  I've updated my question with the solution (tweaked the code to run through multiple regressions and for the relevant slope to be pulled out and applied in the for loop).